# Access form from within Angular $mdDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, angular-material, mddialog

I am using an Angular 1.5 Material Design `$mdDialog` in the recommended way, using `controllerAs: "dialog"`. In the template I have a form: `<form name="fooForm"`. Within the template I can access the form with no problem, e.g. `ng-disabled="fooForm.$invalid || fooForm.$submitted"`.

But how do I access that form from within the `$mdDialog` controller? From what I read, I would expect to be able to do this:

```
    const doFoo = () => {
        if (this.fooForm.$dirty) {
```

Here `this` is the dialog controller.

But I get an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property '$dirty' of undefined`. And sure enough, if I put a breakpoint in the code, the controller has no `fooForm` property.

I've tried using `$scope` as well, but when I put a breakpoint in the code `$scope` has no `fooForm` property either.

Here's my dialog template:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="FooBar">
  <md-toolbar>
    <div class="md-toolbar-tools">
      <h2>FooBar</h2>
      <span flex></span>
      <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="dialog.cancel()">
        <md-icon>close</md-icon>
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </md-toolbar>
  <form name="fooForm" ng-submit="dialog.ok()" novalidate>
    <md-dialog-content>
      <div layout="column" layout-padding>
        <h2 class="md-headline">Foo</h2>
        <div layout="row" layout-xs="column">
          ...
      </div>
    </md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions>
      <md-button class="md-primary" type="submit" ng-disabled="fooForm.$invalid || fooForm.$submitted">
        OK
      </md-button>
      <md-button ng-click="dialog.cancel()">
        Cancel
      </md-button>
    </md-dialog-actions>
  </form>
</md-dialog>
```

How do I access a form in an `$mdDialog` from the dialog controller?

Comment: $scope.fooForm ... as usual

Comment: Ah, so `$scope` is still distinct from my controller? I thought that using `controllerAs` what used to be in `$scope` was now in my controller. I guess that part still confuses me a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to assign the form to the Scope of the Controller. Do this by changing the form name from `fooForm` to `dialog.fooForm`.

```
<form name="dialog.fooForm" ng-submit="dialog.ok()" novalidate>
```

Comment: That was it! I finally tried it today, and it works. Thanks! I want to note that within the form code such as `ng-disabled="fooForm.$invalid"` will also have to be updated accordingly to `ng-disabled="dialog.fooForm.$invalid"`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Scope existed and still exist disregarding controllerAs. When you use 'controllerAs xxx' that just mean - put my controller into scope and name it xxx. You can use them together:

> ```
> function controller($scope) {
>   var vm = this;
>
>   vm.click = function() {}
>
>   $scope.click = function() {}
> }
>
> <button ng-click="xxx.click()" ...
> <button ng-click="click()" ...
> ```

2. Now if you write `ng-click="whatever();smth();"`angular will use `$parse(expression)(scope)` to parse this expression.
3. Now you write `form name="formName"` -- angular will use `$parse("formName").assign(scope, form);` and put it to scope.
4. $parse is quite clever and can easily handle nested properties, to put form to your controller (as xxx): `<form name="xxx.myForm"></form>`

Comment: But I just set a breakpoint and looked at `$scope`, and there is no `fooForm` there, either. Have you tried this with `$mdDialog`?

Comment: Should I guess your template? Or where you log?

Comment: I've added the template to the question. The log is irrelevant --- I'm actually putting breakpoint in the code and examining the `$scope` object.

Comment: Where? In the template or in the controller?

Answer (score 2):

The form is not defined in your controller as a property and therefore you cannot access the form like `if (this.fooForm.$dirty)`.

However you can easily pass it to your method:

```
const doFoo = (fooForm) => {
    if (fooForm.$dirty) {
    ...
```

And in html:

```
ng-click="dialog.cancel(fooForm)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Give your controller name when your `$mdDialog` initialize. see below code:

```
$scope.showDialog = function (ev) {

    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: 'myController',
        templateUrl: 'template.html',
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: false,
        fullscreen: false // Only for -xs, -sm breakpoints.
    })
        .then(function (answer) {
            $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
        }, function () {
            $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
        });
};
```

Make sure you put controller name in quotes when you create separate controller. like `controller: 'myController'`

if you want to pass a function then not quotes needed like `controller: myController,`

In html template use `ng-submit="ok()"` instead of `ng-submit="dialog.ok()"`.

I have created a sample **plnkr** with your template and it is working fine. check [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/aj1oO24Ak5MuhvGir5H1?p=preview)

**EDIT** :`

```
angular.module('BlankApp', ['ngMaterial']).controller('myController', function($scope, $mdDialog) {
        $scope.ok = function () {
            if ($scope.fooForm.$dirty) {
                // do whatever you want
                $mdDialog.hide("mesage");    
            }
        };  
});`
```

Comment: Yes, all this was already working fine for me, too. You must have missed the main point of this question: accessing an HTML _form_ on the dialog from the controller.

Comment: If you have checked the plnkr link, i have created a controller from where you access form of the dialog. adding that snippet too.